# Data is not editable in gridview when through code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dropdown

I have a drop down list in which data is bind from a table, I have another GridV
iew in which same data is to be filled that is present in the DropDown list. 
The data is bind through the code in c#, but then it cannot be edited.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var userid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        ClientAdminMultiView.SetActiveView(MasterFundsView);
        List<T_W_Company> allowedCompanies = Source.aspnet_AdminUserClientMapping.Where(x => x.UserID == userid).Select(p => p.T_W_Company).ToList();
        CompanyDropDown.DataSource = allowedCompanies;
        CompanyDropDown.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataSource = allowedCompanies;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    ClearErrors();
}
```

Below is my asp code that i tried to bind the data to the gridview,
It is a template field.

`<asp:EntityDataSource ID="CompanyDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ReportsEntities"
    ContextTypeName="Nirvana.Factory.ReportsDbModel.ReportsEntities" DefaultContainerName="ReportsEntities"
    EnableFlattening="False" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True"
    EntitySetName="T_W_Company" OnDeleted="MasterFundsDataSource_Deleted" OnDeleting="MasterFundsDataSource_Deleting"
    OnInserted="MasterFundsDataSource_Inserted" OnInserting="MasterFundsDataSource_Inserting"
    OnUpdated="MasterFundsDataSource_Updated" OnUpdating="MasterFundsDataSource_Updating" AutoGenerateWhereClause="true">
            <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="CompanyID" ControlID="CompanyDropDown" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
            DbType="Int64" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your markup. Are you using an TemplateField / ItemTemplate? Also in your code it looks like you are just calling a stored procedure and data binding - nothing related to editing.

The following post has a nice example of an editable GridView.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx

**EDIT**

You just mentioned you are using the EntityDataSource, but where is the rest of your markup. Without seeing everything its hard to give accurate guidance.

That being said,

You need to set the GridView to allow editing. The following posts are bit old, but will walk you through it.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/entitydatasource-control-in-Asp-Net-3-5/
http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/ms/aspdotnet/entitydatasource.html

Comment: I am getting the values from a table for the drop down list. and those values I have to bind to the GridView. If I am binding the data list of data using the above code, I am not able to edit the data in the GridView. Can you suggest me some way to bind the data through asp code using where parameter.

Comment: Where is the rest of the markup? You need to configure the GridView for editing.